# XSS works when I save generated HTML to file, but not directly in browser

Tags: exploit, xss

The hints of [XSS game's level2](https://xss-game.appspot.com/level2)  say that

> Entering a  tag on this level will not work. Try an element
>   with a JavaScript attribute instead.

When entering

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

the resulting HTML after submiting is

```
<td valign="top" class="message-container"> 
  <div class="shim"></div>
   <b>You</b><span class="date">Wed May 18 2016 </span>
   <blockquote><script>alert(91)</script></blockquote>
</td>
```

and the XSS is not triggered. If I replace it with

```
post-content=<img src='foobar' onerror='alert("xss")'>
```

it fires!

I've copied the whole HTML to a separate file on my computer, run the first case and the script fired!

So what is different from case 1 to case 2? Should case 1 work too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant code for the HTML generation is the following:

```
for (var i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {
  var html = '<table class="message"> <tr> <td valign=top> '
    + '<img src="/static/level2_icon.png"> </td> <td valign=top '
    + ' class="message-container"> <div class="shim"></div>';

  html += '<b>You</b>';
  html += '<span class="date">' + new Date(posts[i].date) + '</span>';
  html += "<blockquote>" + posts[i].message + "</blockquote";
  html += "</td></tr></table>"
  containerEl.innerHTML += html;
```

As we can see, the HTML is being set in the DOM via `innerHTML`, which means that the `script` tag will not be executed, because per-specification, `innerHTML` does not execute scripts. More on why can be found on the Stack Overflow question [script tag create with innerHTML of a div doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390588/script-tag-create-with-innerhtml-of-a-div-doesnt-work).

> I've copied the whole html to a separate file on my computer, run the first case and the script fired!

Presumably you copied the resulting HTML which means it was not created by `innerHTML`, but permanently in the HTML source, so it ran.

Comment: I can't figure out why `</blockquote` isn't closed but still appears as is.

Comment: @Xavier59 Auto-magical error handling.